# Issue with resizing custom view in appwidget, can't determine real size appwidget on android, especially on tablets

Tags: android, size, width, android-appwidget

I'm designing an AppWidget and I have run into such problem: I define in xml

```
android:minWidth ="296dp"
android:minHeight="146dp"
```

That means 4x2 cells size of my widget.
In my program code I am creating a custom view by drawing text and figures on canvas. For proper scaling of my custom view I must know the boundary dimensions of my appwidget's placement on homescreen. I couldn't have found any useful information how to determine real appwidget size on homescreen (the all resources have told - "you can't!" - is it really so?) and so I estimated my appwidget size using `android:minWidth` and `android:minHeight="146dp"`.

The problem is that I can't give proper appearance of my widget on all devices which I've used for testing, especially
it concerned tablets.
I've read https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html and other official docs, but I can't come to the right conclusion.

1 -  I've found two formulas for determine size of one cell:

```
1)minWidth or minHeight = 70 * n - 30       and
2)minWidth or minHeight = 74 * n - 2
```

I've used the second and identified that it works perfectly for usual handsets (not for Samsung Galaxy Tab), but the officials offer to use the first one. If I used the first one on handsets it would work too, but I`ve got a less size widget components (size widget components - text, rects and etc. which I draw on canvas), hence the appwidget appearance
is worse than in second case.

In tablet case I've got an empty spaces at right/left of my custom view and having regard to my widget layout (where I have custom widget and two buttons) it looks bad. I think that empty spaces on tablet occured because of mismatch real and estimated width of appwidget.

How can I calculate a size widget that it would look proper on tablets?

2 - I can't use 9-patch resources because I create my view programmatically. I've tried using android:scaleType in layout widget

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />
```

but, for example, in Motorola Xoom I've got bad appearance of my appwidget after stretching custom view.

3 - I figured out that Android device resize widget by itself but I couldn't quiet catch the logic of such resizing.

After all, how to design appwidget size for handset and tablets in my case?
I'll be very grateful to you for your help.

Comment: Alex, I think you should consider dividing your question in smaller and more focused ones. That way you could get more attention to this issue

Comment: Main question is: how to determine the real size of widget cell on every device...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible - I had the same problem with my app widget.
Instead you can create different versions of your app widget (i.e. 1x4, 2x3 etc), but I know that is not what you really want to.
The scaling done within the app widget of for instance text inside TextView (even with sp) seeems to be beyond our control in appwidgets.